# meteor project create single instance with multiple theme like Admin, Frontend

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to use different different types of template in client side and admin side using meteor like bellow example scenario

www.sitename.com - main site with theme1 for frontend 
(http://seo-html.axiomthemes.com/)

www.sitename.com/manager - administrator dashboard with theme2 with backend (http://themes-lab.com/pixit/admin/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the roles package to define who has access to each template, in this way you can implement both themes that you mention here.

You can add the packages with: 
`meteor add accounts-password alanning:roles`